# initial jquery not working when updatepanel is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have reviewed posts about this issue but none of solutions seem to work for me.

I have a js file with jquery scripts which is loaded in head section of the page

I have also an updatepanel which holds a child usercontrol where my trigger button is placed.
The updatepanel is updated when a child button is clicked correctly.

Everything works fine except that jquery doesn't work anymore.

I found info that $(document).ready does not work on partial postback so it is the case of my updatepanel.

I have also found information that adding path with ScriptReference can work so I added this to my Page_Load of the usercontrol holding UpdatePanel:

```
    ScriptReference sr = new ScriptReference("~/js/jquerycripts.js");
    ScriptManager.Scripts.Add(sr);
```

But it doesn't work either.

Not sure what else to try.

Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: This article fixed it for me. [Fix jQuery within updatepanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534587/ASP-NET-jQuery-is-not-Working-in-UpdatePanels)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code instead of $(document).ready(YourFunctionName);

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(YourFunctionName)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your child button inside the updatepanel triggers jQuery code. You are attaching the onclick behavior on document ready. When you refresh your content, the initial child button is gone. It might be replaced with a new one, but the new one doesn't have the onclick behavior, just as expected.

The easiest way to fix this would be **event delegation**: attach the onclick event to a parent of your updatepanel that won't be refreshed. See this page for more details: http://api.jquery.com/on/ . In your case, on() would be applied to the parent, and selector would be your child button.

Another way would be to re-run your jQuery code after each updatepanel load.

Comment: jQuery is loaded from .js file on page load in head section like other js and css files. The button triggers the update of updatepanel, it doesn't trigger the jquery specifically. The problem is that the updated updatepanel doesn't reload the original jquery (from .js) to its content so all jquery I used for updatepanel content is lost on panel update. I don't know how to reload original jquery on panel update.